# Issue while trying to patch SUSE Server AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, patch, sles

I'm really stuck with this for a while now so thought of reaching out to wider audience to see if anyone face a similar issue.

I'm trying to patch SLES server 15-SP1, but I'm not able to. I see below error in the logs.

====Cloudregister Logs====

```text
2021-06-08 14:23:00,314 INFO:Forced new registration
2021-06-08 14:23:00,321 INFO:No current registration server set.
2021-06-08 14:23:00,322 INFO:Using API: regionInfo
2021-06-08 14:23:00,328 INFO:Region server arguments: ?regionHint=me-south-1
2021-06-08 14:23:00,328 INFO:Getting update server information, attempt 1
2021-06-08 14:23:00,328 INFO:   Using region server: 54.223.148.145
2021-06-08 14:23:01,346 INFO:No current registration server set.
2021-06-08 14:23:01,373 INFO:Modified /etc/hosts, added: 157.175.6.182  smt-ec2.susecloud.net   smt-ec2

2021-06-08 14:23:02,674 INFO:Writing SMT rootCA: /usr/share/pki/trust/anchors
2021-06-08 14:23:02,689 INFO:Updating CA certificates: update-ca-certificates
2021-06-08 14:23:03,211 ERROR:Registration with ('157.175.6.182', None) failed. Trying ('15.185.47.44', None)
2021-06-08 14:23:03,211 INFO:Clean current registration server: ('157.175.6.182', None)
2021-06-08 14:23:03,212 INFO:Modified /etc/hosts, added: 15.185.47.44   smt-ec2.susecloud.net   smt-ec2

2021-06-08 14:23:03,432 ERROR:Registration with ('15.185.47.44', None) failed. Trying ('157.175.138.207', None)
2021-06-08 14:23:03,432 INFO:No current registration server set.
2021-06-08 14:23:03,432 INFO:Modified /etc/hosts, added: 157.175.138.207        smt-ec2.susecloud.net   smt-ec2

2021-06-08 14:23:03,646 ERROR:Baseproduct registration failed
2021-06-08 14:23:03,646 ERROR:  Registering system to registration proxy https://smt-ec2.susecloud.net

Announcing system to https://smt-ec2.susecloud.net ... SSL verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate Certificate issuer: /C=DE/ST=Bavaria/L=Nuremberg/O=SUSE/OU=CSM/CN=SUSE/emailAddress=suse-public-cloud@susecloud.net Certificate subject: /C=DE/ST=Bavaria/L=Nuremberg/O=SUSE/OU=Public Cloud/CN=Update server certificate (smt-ec2.susecloud.net)/emailAddress=suse-public-cloud@susecloud.net SUSEConnect error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

====================================================================

Any help or lead is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this steps can help you:

1. download the ssl certificate to local machine (with openssl)

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect smt-ec2.susecloud.net:443 -servername smt-ec2.susecloud.net\
    | openssl x509 > /tmp/smt-ec2.susecloud.net.cert
```

2. copy the certificate

```
cp /tmp/smt-ec2.susecloud.net.cert /etc/pki/trust/anchors/
```

3. import the certificate:

```
update-ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are performing the update directly on the SUSE instance. An option to better manage the execution of patches in AWS would be through Patch Manager. The Patch Manager can be run under AWS Systems manager that abstracts this type of management and makes it easier to be performed.

Patch manager through Systems manager allows you to abstract update management administration at the OS level, focusing only on the cloud layer without having to worry about running a "yum update" or "apt-get update", the Patch Manager have automatic rollback and output of logs that are great to debug this type of problem.

To configure the patch manager you need to have the SSM agent installed on the machine, this procedure is very simple, you can run a script to do the installation, in addition SSM Agent will allow you to perform other actions with Systems Manager.

How to install SSM Agent in SUSE Servers:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/agent-install-sles.html

After installation succeed you need to configure patch execution. You can follow this guide too:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-patch.html

Also, regarding your error:

```
Baseproduct registration failed 2021-06-08 14:23:03,646 ERROR: Registering system to registration proxy https://smt-ec2.susecloud.net
```

Apparently the server (EC2 instance) is not able to connect to the license register on SUSE or even cannot find the patch address for the cloud-facing suse license type. You can try opening a ticket with suse or AWS and report this error, indicating that it is impacting a production environment. They will surely guide you through the steps to correctly register the license in the cloud model, because the suse and AWS have some partnership to support this types of servers ([About SUSE and AWS support](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019601))

Steps to correct this SMT (Subscription Management tool) based on a suse KB ([Suse Reference](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018784)):

Ensure the SMT Server has enabled and mirrored all the necessary SLES12 SP2 Repositories (e.g. SLES12-SP2-Pool, SLES12-SP2-Updates):

1. Navigate to YaST ->  "Network Services" -> "SMT Server Management" GUI Wizard.
2. Select and enable the necessary SLES12 SP2 related Repositories.
3. Start the SMT mirror operation.

After the SMT mirror operation has completed, the SUSEConnect command should be able to register the SMT Client machine successfully.

After that, try to run the update again.

Comment: Thank you Luis for your response. I found out that the issue was related to openssl. for some reason it was not pointing to the correct root CA and the instance was unable to register with SUSE SMT.